# Google Static MAPS API url resulting in 500 error

Tags: google-maps-api-3, static

I am using the google static maps API and have the following url:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?sensor=false&size=400x400&markers=icon:http://localhost/SimpleApp/images/SubjectIcon.png%7c44.942065,-93.66287&markers=icon:http://localhost/SimpleApp/images/BlueIcon.png%7c41.9922652,-87.7832879&markers=icon:http://localhost/SimpleApp/images/BlueIcon.png%7c44.0221363,-92.4666658

The problem is, I get a 500 error using this url. Could anyone help me see what I am missing?

TIA

Comment: For one...you are using `localhost` icons that nobody will have on their machine to test

Comment: Just pasted the actual image that I am using. It can be replaced with any custom image url

Comment: Super late, but I'll mention, this error only happens when it tries to use http, not https. It's very bizarre.

Answer (score 2):

The URL in your sample is looking for icons hosting locally via `http://localhost` which Google Maps can't find. Changing those URLs to publicly available images should work fine.  As an example, the following URL works fine:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?sensor=false&size=400x400&markers=icon:http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f4/Blue_icon.png%7c44.942065,-93.66287&markers=icon:http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f4/Blue_icon.png%7c41.9922652,-87.7832879&markers=icon:http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f4/Blue_icon.png%7c44.0221363,-92.4666658
```

Comment: Great, then please mark this as the answer so that it doesn't come up as an unanswered question.